# Как сделать на CSS колечки на линии

Tags: css3, html5

Кто нибудь с таки сталкивался? Нужно в landing page реализовать три колечка на линии. [image: секция в landing page]

Comment: самый простой вариант использовать изображение

Answer (score 15):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circles {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #00878B;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  border: 20px solid #00878B;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto -20px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #00878B;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Классно Респект.

Answer (score 8):

Вариант на градиентах. В этом случае нет тени на белом фоне.

```css
.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, darkcyan 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(transparent 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 85%, transparent 85%);
  background-repeat: norepeat-x;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.circle::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: darkcyan;
  width: 50%;
  height: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

.circle::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: darkcyan;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 30%, transparent 85%);
  width: 50%;
  height: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -100;
}

.content {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  top: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Основано на предыдущем ответе `soledar10`.

Для автора. 3 колечки

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circles {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #00878B;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  border: 20px solid #00878B;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto -20px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  float: left;
}
.circles>.circle:first-child{
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.circles>.circle:nth-child(2){
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #00878B;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```